# Redirecting from nested methods in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is a code similar to one I have. What I need to do is to redirect from a nested method to other page and **stop execution all actions it was called from**. In this this case it's method2. It should redirect to `'/home/index'` and I need to prevent redirecting to `'/home/index123'`

```
    class MyController::ApplicationController

    def index
     #some work
      method1
     #some work  that must be done if there is no redirect
     #some work   that must be done if there is no redirect
      redirect_to '/home/index123' 
    end

    private

    def method1
     #some work
     method2
     #some work that must be done if there is no redirect
     #some work  that must be done if there is no redirect
    end

    def method2
     #some work
     #I need to redirect to other page just from here!
     redirect_to '/home/index'
    end


end
```

Your ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your redirection a variable.  Set this variable as the return value of your method.
For instance:

```
 def method2
   #some work
   #I need to redirect to other page just from here!
   '/home/index'
 end



def index
     #some work
      to_action = method1
      redirect_to to_action
    end
```

Comment: I have 2 private methods and it would be not good because I would have to check this variable in each method and in index.

Comment: didn't understand your concern

Comment: I updated index and method1. Look at them. The bottom line is, that I want to redirect right away, right here I would call it.

Comment: why would you want to repeat the redirect logic in three methods if you can do it in just one, as in my solution.  all you need to do is set redirects in one of your private methods and if that's nil set the to_action variable in your index action to the default url.  this solution is clean, avoids duplication of code, makes it easier to read.

Comment: You forgot that index has "#some work  that must be done if there is no redirect". So if there is a way to redirect this work must not be done.

Comment: that's what i said.  check if your private methods return anything, if not set the variable to the redirect url.  then you can use just one "redirect_to" statement to redirect to the appropriate url